# MISRA Error due to Wraparound of unsigned arithmetic operator

Tags: c++, c, misra

I am having an issue for MISRA standards regarding wraparound error. I have tried to resolve it by having a look at options available on internet but remained unable to resolve it as remained unable to find some viable solution.

I am providing a simple example to explain my situation.

I am having  a wraparound error in result line due to MISRA standards. Wraparound in unsigned arithmetic operation.

Can someone provide me a reason why it is happening and how to cater this situation.

Thanks a lot.

```
 unsigned int x;
 unsigned int y;
 unsigned int z;
 unsigned int result;

 x= 0;
 y = 60;
 z = 60;

 result = x-y +z;
```

Comment: `x - y` is `0 - 60`, which wraps around—since `unsigned int` cannot be negative.

Comment: @Dietrich Epp thanks for your comment whats should be the viable solution to overcome this wraparound

Comment: Without knowing what the code is supposed to do, it’s hard to say. What is the code supposed to do? What range of values is it supposed to work on?

Comment: Do you really need full MISRA compliance in your program? MISRA is very strict, almost overly strict, and disallows many things that are really valid C (or C++).

Comment: Well, the example in your real program will have unknown values for the variables. You must ensure that they cannot overflow/underflow, or you must make sure that overflow and underflow are OK. (I think the -- well defined -- C++/C rules for unsigned underflow will make the computation result in the expected value though.)

Comment: Presumably this is MISRA-C, rule 12.11 (don't make us guess).  It is *advisory*, not required.  It points out that this expression is evaluated by the compiler, not at runtime, and therefore uses unsigned long instead of unsigned int.  Not something to worry about, compilers know how to do this correctly, merely advisory.

Comment: `result = (x + z) - y;`

Comment: "wraparound error in result line due to MISRA standards." --> post exact error.

Comment: @HansPassant Can't be, 12.11 from deprecated MISRA-C:2004 is about unsigned wrap around of _constant expressions_. The equivalent rule in MISRA-C:2012 is 12.4.

Comment: @Peter As it stands your question is unclear and cannot be answered. You need to clarify 1) which programming language you are using, it can't be C and C++ at the same time, 2) which MISRA version you are using, 3) which MISRA rule that the tool pointed at, and 4) which static analyser that is giving you this error for the posted code.

Comment: @HansPassant Re "evaluated by the compiler, not at runtime, and therefore uses unsigned long": That's interesting, I would not have thought that. Is the statement true in both languages?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It has nothing to do with the language standards. In theory/as far as the standard is concerned, the calculation happens in run-time. In practice, this particular snippet will get optimized by any decent compile into a single compile-time constant. But that's not what the MISRA rule is about.

Comment: @Lundin I was surprised not at the possibility of a compile time computation but at the possibility that they could be done with `unsigned long`. As far as I can see it would not make a difference. The result of the **computation** may be different with `unsigned long` because an overflow occurring with `unsigned int` for large values of `z` is prevented; but the assignment of the large result to `result`which is only an `unsigned int` will result in the same value, just later. The standard is concerned simply through the as-if rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dietrich Epp remarked correctly, the code analyzer observes that for the given values — which are known and visible at compile time — the sub-expression `x-y` will mathematically be negative. Negative values are out of the value range of unsigned types, they cannot be represented; such a situation is called an *overflow*. It is well-defined for unsigned integers in C++ (6.7.1/4 plus footnote 45 in the [standard draft n4713](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)) and in C (6.2.5/9 in the [standard draft n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)): "Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation."

Modulo arithmetic "wraps around". One can image the possible values as a circle where the maximum (all bits set) and minimum (no bit set) values are *adjacent*. Like with all other adjacent values I can go from one to the other by adding or subtracting 1: `((uint8_t)0xff+1 == 0`, and correspondingly `((uint8_t)0-1 == 0xff`. (The bit pattern 0xff... to represent -1 in the usual 2-complement is known to most programmers, but it may still come as a surprise when it results from a computation.) In a 2-complement representation this transition comes naturally because `0xfff... +1` is `0x10000...`, with the carry bit, the leading 1, "to the left" of the bits in the machine representation; it is simply thrown away.

The bottom line is: Perhaps surprisingly a small negative value like -60 assigned to an unsigned int results in a large number. This is what MISRA alerts you of.

In your particular case, with the values given, there is no issue because in modulo arithmetic addition is still the inverse operation to subtraction no matter the values so that `0-60+60` is 0. But problems may arise if z is, say, 58, so the result is -2; this would result in the second-highest value assigned to `result` which its type can hold. *That* may have disastrous consequences if e.g. the value is used to terminate a for loop. With signed integers the loop would be skipped; with unsigned integers it will, probably wrongly, run for a long time.

After clarifying the underlying issue the following questions arise:

1. As demonstrated the computation is well defined with unsigned operands and, with the given arguments, has an unsurprising result. Are you happy with *all* results which can occur with *all* possible argument values and combinations — that is, are you are happy with modulo arithmetic?

   1a. Yes: Then the question is whether you want or must prevent the warning. Technically, there is nothing to do. Any change would likely obscure matters. Apparently, MISRA warnings [can be suppressed](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Suppression-of-the-MISRA-C-rules-in-code).

   1b. If that is not possible or desired your software development process will likely have a mechanism to *qualify* such warnings as acceptable.

   1c. If that is not possible or desired you'll have to (unnecessarily) complicate your code. One solution is to simply perform the computation with 64 bit signed integers which are guaranteed to be able to hold all 32 bit unsigned values (assuming that `sizeof int == 32` on your system), and assign the result with an explicit cast to indicate that the possible overflow and loss of information is intentional.

   Or, if in your data `y < z && x + z < UINT_MAX` always holds, you can simply re-order the evaluation to `result = x + z - y;`, never encountering negative values in sub-expressions.
2. If you are *unhappy* with modulo arithmetic, especially with the possibility of unexpectedly large results, you have to step back and reconsider the data model you are using for your real-world data. Maybe you must qualify your data and prevent negative outcomes, or you must use signed integers, or something else is amiss.

Comment: "This is what MISRA alerts you of" No it isn't, because the expression isn't a constant expression.

Comment: @Lundin I suppose that the code checker (as many modern compilers) flags  value issues which are obvious at compile time even if the arguments are not constants or constant expressions. But I agree with chux that the OP should post the real code (as far as possible) and the real warning.

Comment: The very rationale for rule 12.4 is that while there may be valid reasons for run-time wrap-around, there should very few such reasons to do this intentionally for compile-time constants.

Comment: While all tools give you a mechanism for "shutting the tool up" use it with caution.  This is *not* a false positive, so fixing the code is the correct approach, not ignoring it!  And if you do, this should be document by way of a deviation or other mechanism.

Comment: @Andrew with the given values (and generally with all similar value pairs) *it is* a false positive. Of course [you cannot later plug that software into the next generation rocket](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0426/) without proper re-review.